# Unable to retrieve the data from angular service to be displayed in a component

Tags: angular, angular-services

Problem Statement:
Unable to retrieve the data from angular service

**Sequence of screen navigation:**
Product list screen/component-->select a specific product -->Navigate to Product Details screen/component

**Data storage approach:**
1.Created angular service
2.Upon the selection of a product--> called a function to store the selected product infromation in the angular service
3.In the product details component.ts--> retrieve the stored product information from the angular service

**Issue encountered:**
Data is being store in angular service=Working fine
However unable to retrieve the data from angular service-- getting empty

**cptservice.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from  'rxjs/operators';
import {Service} from '../modelangular/service.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CptserviceService {
    selectedProductToDelete: Service[] = [];
    
    deleteProduct(selectedProductDelete: Service) {
      this.selectedProductToDelete.push(selectedProductDelete);
    }
  
    getProducts() {
      return this.selectedProductToDelete
    }
}
```

**productlist.component.html**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let service of CptserviceService.servicesFromMongoDB "> 
      <td>1 </td>
      <td> {{service.cptcode}}</td>
      <td> {{service.cptdescription}}</td>
      <td> {{service.grossFixedPrice}}</td>
      <td> {{service.discountedCashPrice}}</td>
      <td> {{service.payerSpecificNegotiatedPrice}}</td>
      <td> {{service.deidentifiedMinimumPrice}}</td>
      <td> {{service.deidentifiedMaximumPrice}}</td>
      <td>  <a (click)="onclickProductDelete(service)">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash3" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M6.5 1h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1H6v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5ZM11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1H2.506a.58.58 0 0 0-.01 0H1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h.538l.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 0 4.885 16h6.23a2 2 0 0 0 1.994-1.84l.853-10.66h.538a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-.995a.59.59 0 0 0-.01 0H11Zm1.958 1-.846 10.58a1 1 0 0 1-.997.92h-6.23a1 1 0 0 1-.997-.92L3.042 3.5h9.916Zm-7.487 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .528.47l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.998.06L5 5.03a.5.5 0 0 1 .47-.53Zm5.058 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .47.53l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 1-.998-.06l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .528-.47ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Z"/>
        </svg>
            </a> </td>
          </tr>
```

**productlist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute,ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from  'rxjs/operators';
import { Service } from 'src/app/modelangular/service.model';
import { CptserviceService } from 'src/app/servicesangular/cptservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productlist',
  templateUrl: './productlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productlist.component.css'],
  providers:[ CptserviceService]
})
export class ProductlistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    public CptserviceService:CptserviceService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshGetMyServicelistFromMongodb();
  }

refreshGetMyServicelistFromMongodb(){
    this.CptserviceService.getMyServicelistFromMongodb().subscribe( (res: any)=>{
      this.CptserviceService.servicesFromMongoDB=  res; 
      console.log('get my services from mongo db object:', res);
      console.log('get my services from servicesFromMongoDB  object:', this.CptserviceService.servicesFromMongoDB);
    })
  }

  onclickProductDelete(selectedProductDelete:Service){
    console.log("Selected product from my product screen to delete",selectedProductDelete);
    console.log("Selected product from my product screen to delete from angular service:BEFORE ", this.CptserviceService.selectedProductToDelete );
  this.CptserviceService.deleteProduct(selectedProductDelete);
this.CptserviceService.selectedServiceFromDeleteServiceForm );
      console.log("Selected product from my product screen to delete from angular service::AFTER ", this.CptserviceService.selectedProductToDelete ); 
                 this.router.navigate(['/productdetails']);
  }
}
```

**productdetails.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{CptserviceService} from 'src/app/servicesangular/cptservice.service';
import {Service} from 'src/app/modelangular/service.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-productdetails',
  templateUrl: './productdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productdetails.component.css']
})
export class ProductdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  items = this.CptserviceService.selectedProductToDelete;

constructor(
    public CptserviceService : CptserviceService
  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('selected product from component.ts:', this.items);
    console.log('selected product from component angular service:', this.CptserviceService.selectedProductToDelete);
    
  }

     }
```

**productdetails.component.html**

```
<h3>Product Details</h3>
<div  *ngFor="let item of items">
  <span>{{ item.cptcode }}</span>
  <span>{{ item.cptdescription }}</span>
  
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Screen shot 3:( Depicts the console.log for service array and service function GetProducts AFTER update. Both log the same object
[image]

Screen shot 4:( Depicts the console.log for onit)
[image]

Screen shot 5:( Depicts the console.log for onit)
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to log `this.CptserviceService.getProducts()` in your AFTER?

Comment: @MishaMashina, Thank you . Yes, I logged . Please refer to Screen shot 3:( Depicts the console.log for service array and service function GetProducts AFTER update. Both log the same object

Comment: How about in productdetails.ts putting `this.items = this.CptserviceService.getProducts()` in onInit?

Comment: @MishaMashina : Please refer to the screen shot 4:( Depicts the console.log for onit). It does not retrieve the value i.e. empty

Comment: But you didn't put it in onInit...?

Comment: @MishaMashina Please refer to the screen shot 5:( Depicts the console.log for onit). It does not retrieve the value i.e. empty

Comment: @MishaMashina: Finally got it working . The issue was that imported the service and mentioned in the component.ts [Provider:service]. Removed this and mentioned [Provider:service] in the app.module.ts

Comment: Ah, nice to hear you've worked it out, good work!

Answer (score 0):

@MishaMashina: Finally got it working . The issue was that imported the service and mentioned in the component.ts [Provider:service]. Removed this and mentioned [Provider:service] in the app.module.ts

**productlist.component.ts (before)**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-productlist',
  templateUrl: './productlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productlist.component.css'],
providers:[ CptserviceService]
})
```

**productlist.component.ts ( After.. issue resolved)**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-productlist',
  templateUrl: './productlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productlist.component.css'],
})
```